# How use "find_previous_siblings" of BeatifulSoup to find <strong> tag?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to do web scraping on a page that doesn't use much h1, h2, h3 structures, etc.
It predominantly uses the **strong** tag. I want to search for a specific word (in a **p** tag) and, if I find it, also take the texts from above levels (tagged with **strong**) ...

I noticed that my lists created with the command `i.find_previous_siblings ('strong')` return blank list. While if I use `soup.body.findAll ('strong')` it works, returning a huge list of items (is what I need!!)

How to get the list of strong tags using the function `find_previous_siblings`??

Examples / This worked (and print a huge list):

```
url = 'http://www.mpsp.mp.br/portal/page/portal/DO_Estado/2020/DO_20-06-2020.html'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for i in soup.body.findAll('strong'):
    print(i.text.strip())
```

Not worked (print empty list):

```
url = 'http://www.mpsp.mp.br/portal/page/portal/DO_Estado/2020/DO_20-06-2020.html'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for i in soup.body.contents:
    if isinstance(i, element.NavigableString):
        continue
    if isinstance(i, element.Tag):
        texts = i.text
        if texts == 'HELENA BONILHA DE TOLEDO LEITE':
            print(i.find_previous_siblings('h1'))
            print(i.find_previous_siblings('strong'))
            print(i)
```

Comment: They're not siblings... the siblings are other `p` tags - the `strong` tags are inside those `p` tags...

Comment: It'd also help if you could describe your desired output for `''HELENA BONILHA DE TOLEDO LEITE''` and the rationale behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not siblings because the strong is inside another paragraph tag, `p`.

I think you want `find_previous` like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, element
import requests

url = 'http://www.mpsp.mp.br/portal/page/portal/DO_Estado/2020/DO_20-06-2020.html'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for i in soup.body.contents:
    if isinstance(i, element.NavigableString):
        continue
    if isinstance(i, element.Tag):
        texts = i.text
        if texts == 'HELENA BONILHA DE TOLEDO LEITE':
            print(i.find_previous('h1'))
            print(i.find_previous('strong'))
            print(i)
```

Documentation explaining `find_previous` and `find_all_previous`:
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-previous-and-find-previous

Comment: @michelmetran Also if you need all the 'strongs' up to the 'h1' you can probably just iterate through the `i.previous_elements` yourself building up the list of strong tags.  Its not clear if you just want one strong or all the strongs up to a limit.